# In MDX, calculate the sales rank of a given shop

Tags: mdx, business-intelligence, pentaho

I have an [OLAP cube](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olap_cube) containing the sales count for each of my shops.

Using [MDX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_Expressions), how can I output the rank of a given shop?

I am dreaming about something like below (*does not work*), it would return 8 if SomeShop is the 8th most-selling shop:

```
SELECT RANK( [Shop].CHILDREN, [Shop].[SomeShop]) from [Sales]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I have found.
Any better solution would be greatly appreciated.

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[rank] AS RANK(
      [Shop].CurrentMember,
      Order(
         [Shop].Members,
         [Measures].[salescount],
         BDESC
      ),
      [Measures].[salescount]
   )
SELECT Order(
         [Shop].Members,
         [Measures].[salescount],
         BDESC
      ).Item([SomeShop]) ON COLUMNS,
[Measures].[salescount] ON ROWS
FROM [Sales]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the examples on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144726.aspx), the last example will work here.
Something like this:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[rank] AS RANK( [Shop].CurrentMember, [Shop].MEMBERS)
SELECT {[Measures].[rank], ...} on 0
ORDER([Shop].MEMBERS, [Measures].[rank], ASC) on 1
FROM [Sales]
```